# Как вставить картинку из интернета в кнопку?

Tags: python, изображения, tkinter

Мне понравилась одна картинка в интернете и мне нужно вставить её в кнопку. Но можете подсказать как вставить картинку в кнопку. И можно ли вместо пути     к картинке вписать ссылку на картинку из интернета.

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

some_button=Button(root) # в эту кнопку нужно вставить картинку
some_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Ссылка для примера:
https://some_image...

Comment: В гугл `tkinter image from url`. Первая ссылка. Меньше минуты времени.

Comment: это не надёжно.эту картинку могут там удалить. пкм по ней и сохранить себе